# Problem in importing : The requested module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

I want to import a custom hook I just created named `useLocalStorage` but i've been getting this error:

> The requested module '/src/hooks/useLocalStorage.jsx?t=1688798057310' does not provide an export named 'useLocalStorage' (at App.jsx:12:10)___

This is the export statement

```js
export default function useLocalStorage(key, value) {
  const saveValue = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value)
  }
  return saveValue
}
```

This is the import statement

```js
import { useLocalStorage } from './hooks/useLocalStorage'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `export default ...` which doesn't create a *named export*. Thus you cannot use it like a named export. (See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) for details)

Either change the import to

```
import useLocalStorage from "./hooks/useLocalStorage"
```

to import your *default* export as `useLocalStorage`

or change your export to

```
export function useLocalStorage(...) {
  ...
}
```

to create a *named* export.

Answer (score 3):

```js
export default function useLocalStorage(key, value) {
 const saveValue = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value)
 }
 return saveValue
}
```

then :

```
import useLocalStorage from './hooks/useLocalStorage'
```

### OR

```js
export function useLocalStorage(key, value) {
 const saveValue = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value)
 }
 return saveValue
}
```

then:

```js
import {useLocalStorage} from './hooks/useLocalStorage'
```

Answer (score 1):

the import statement is trying to import a named export called useLocalStorage from the module /src/hooks/useLocalStorage.jsx?t=1688798057310, but that module does not provide a named export with that name. Instead, it provides a default export which is the function useLocalStorage.

To fix this error, you can change the import statement to:

```
import useLocalStorage from './hooks/useLocalStorage'
```

This will import the default export of the module which is the useLocalStorage function.